# Casting Abstract Type Object to Derived Type

Tags: c#

I have a third party API that passes a parameter that is a base type. I handle each derived type separately as they have specialized functionality for each that I need to make use of.

```
if(parameter is DerivedTypeX) HandleParamerter(parameter as DerivedTypeX);
else if (parameter is DerivedTypeY) HandleParameter(parameter as DerivedTypeY);
...
```

For some reason, I can't let it go that there must be a more elegant way to handle this parameter than a massive else if block.

Comment: C# supports [pattern matching in `switch/case` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements), so you could write your `if` chain as `switch` statement if that helps.

Comment: Why don't you declare Handle() as an abstract method in your base class, and implement the desired functionality in the derived classes?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't control the third-party API that is passing "parameter".

Comment: Well then map it to your own type, or wrap it, or make it a partial class, or...

Comment: @RenéVogt A switch statement is, semantically, no different than a massive if/else block.

My preference would be to use something like:

HandleParameter(parameter) that uses the correct overload based on the derived type of parameter.

Comment: @CodeCaster Essentially the if/else block _is_ mapping it to my own type. I can't make it a partial class as I don't control the architecture of the third party API passing me the abstract type, "parameter".

Comment: @Fildor Yes... except that, because "parameter" is always the base, abstract type, 
Handle( A obj ) is always the overload called.

Comment: Yep, I got it. Missed the problem by an inch.

Comment: @Fildor Yeah. It's more like the following:
A a = new AB();
    A ab = new AB();
    A ac = new AC();

which is why Handle(A obj) is always called. You're thinking is along the same lines as mine though which is why I can't seem to let it go.

Comment: Yes, realized my mistake right on hitting <enter> to send the comment :-/

Comment: @CodeCaster The first link is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I'd never have found it with that different wording though.

Comment: Example with dynamic: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8NWrLE ... that's awesome. I never even considered `dynamic` before, really.

Comment: @Fildor Me neither. Great solution!